# Cross-windows compitability in C# with layout and language

Tags: c#, windows-7, windows-xp, compatibility

I am developing a C# Application with the .Net Framework and Visual Studio 2005 on Windows 7. On Windows 7 it looks like I want it to. But when I run the program on Windows XP, the layout is not the same as in Windows 7. Some buttons are in slightly different positions and a Panel in a SplitContainer was much larger.

I tried to changing the DPI of XP to 120 DPI with no success. I created it as a multilingual application and it works well on 7. But again when I started it with XP, I still have problems. It only runs an English version of the application even if I start it on a German version of XP.

Had anyone faced these issues? Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Thomas

Comment: Are you sure the fonts are the same? e.g. MS Sans Serif vs. Verdana/Tahoma/Trebuchet (or whatever Aero Glass uses)

Answer (score 1):

I just found a way to deal with the formating problem.

I had to set the Form Property AutoScalMode to "Dpi" and it works fine.